# basis of a tensor space!

Tags: tensors

Could you please explain to me how to write a tensor in terms of its components and a basis? Actually, I couldn't understand the form of the tensor space basis [which is a product of the basis vectors and the dual basis vectors: "T = Tαβ ωβ ⊗ eα" where "Tαβ" are the components, "ωβ" are the dual basis vectors (of a dual vector space) and "eα" are basis vector(of a vector space)]

Thank you

Comment: Well, assuming that $\{\omega_\beta \}$ and $\{e_\alpha \}$ are bases for two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ respectively, then $\{\omega_\beta \otimes e_\alpha\}$ is a basis for $V \otimes W$. So any element of this space (which is a tensor) can be represented by a linear combination of $ {\omega_\beta \otimes e_\alpha } $ so can be written as $\sum T^{\alpha \beta} \omega_{\beta} \otimes e_\alpha$

Answer (score 1):

The kind of tensor you chose is of type 
**"rank two mixed tensor"** and this, correctly written, is
$$T=T_{\beta}{}^{\alpha}\ \omega^{\beta}\otimes e_{\alpha},$$
also this formal bi-indexed linear combination can be interpreted
as a bilinear map 
$$T:V\times V^*\to\mathbb R$$
which you can treat by
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(v,f)&=&T_{\beta}{}^{\alpha}\ \omega^{\beta}\otimes e_{\alpha}(v,f),\\
\\
&=&T_{\beta}{}^{\alpha}\ \omega^{\beta}(v)f(e_{\alpha}),\\
\\
&=&T_{\beta}{}^{\alpha}\ v^{\beta}f_{\alpha},
\end{eqnarray*}
since

- $\omega^{\beta}(e_{\alpha})=\delta^{\beta}_{\alpha}$,
- $\omega^{\beta}(v)=v^{\beta}$,
- $f=f_{\sigma}\omega^{\sigma}$ and
- $f(e_{\mu})=f_{\mu}$.

Comment: Hello! Can you explain why $(\omega^{\beta}\otimes e_{\alpha})(v,f) = \omega^{\beta}(v)f(e_{\alpha})$ and do you have a good reference for this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. If each covector $\omega^k:V\to\mathbb R$ via $$\omega^k(v)=\omega^k(v^se_s)=v^s\delta^k{}_s=v^k,$$ with the dual one does $$e_l:V^*\to\mathbb R$$ defined by $$e_l(f)=e_l(f_t\omega^t)=f_t\omega^t(e_l)=f_t\delta^t{}_l=f_l.$$ That's the way a basic vector induce a linear functional in the dual. Then you use these two to construct bilinear maps on $V\times V\to\mathbb R$, $V\times V^*\to\mathbb R$, $V^*\times V\to\mathbb R$ and $V^*\times V^*\to\mathbb R$. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map for a reference.

Comment: @publicIDI: Also check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763290/is-there-a-fundamental-problem-with-extending-matrix-concepts-to-tensors/2770971#2770971

Comment: Thanks! I had a micro insight while I was sleeping, the subject is new to me and I struggle a bit with the notation, I realized that $\omega^k$ and $e_l$ can be seen as tensors! The last thing I'm unsure is: is $(\omega^k\otimes e_l)(v,f)$ a tensor product $(T^1_0V\otimes T^0_1V)(v,f) = (T^{1+0}_{0+1}V)(v,f) = (T^1_1V)(v,f) = T^0_1(f)\cdot T^1_0V(v)$  by definition of the tensor product between $T^0_1V$ and $T^1_0V$ with $\cdot$ the scalar multiplication, or I'm totally missreading the notation?

Comment: @publicIDI: Let me say it so:  $e_s , v\in T^1_0(V)$ and $\omega^s , f\in T^0_1(V)$, then $$e_i\otimes\omega^j\in T^1_0(V)\otimes T^0_1(V),$$ and $e_i\otimes\omega^j$ maps $V^*\times V\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you! That makes perfectly sense to me  :)

Comment: You could write $T^1_0(V)\otimes T^0_1(V)=T^1_1(V)$ for the space of rank two mixed $(1,1)$-tensors.